# Can't detect 4th graphics card

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I have a strange problem where Ubuntu 16.04 can't detect my 4th graphics card. If I run lspci, I get the following output:

```
[~, 1s]: lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5912 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
```

Yet, if I look at NVIDIA X Server Settings, it's not there:
[image]

And furthermore, in `ethminer`, what I'm actually trying to use the GPU's for, it only detects the first 3:

```
 ⚡   13:19:29.875|gpuminer0  Worker stopping 422 ms
  ℹ  13:19:29.875|gpuminer0  workLoop 1 #f641c97b… #f641c97b…
 ⚡   13:19:29.876|gpuminer1  Worker stopping 422 ms
  ℹ  13:19:29.876|gpuminer1  workLoop 1 #f641c97b… #f641c97b…
 ⚡   13:19:29.896|gpuminer2  Worker stopping 442 ms
  ℹ  13:19:29.896|gpuminer2  workLoop 1 #f641c97b… #f641c97b…
```

I'm somewhat at a loss, I've checked all the hardware, the PCIe risers, the cables. I've used a separate power supply for 2 of the GPU's, all the hardware seems to be working fine, it just can't recognize the 4th GPU.

My motherboard is the Strix Z270 HD.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's quite possible that the closed-source Nvidia driver has a hard limit for the number of cards it supports. Ask the Nvidia support. Alternatively, try `nouveau`.

Comment: May also be a motherboard limit, or some sort of BIOS issue compatibility.  Had hard time to get 2 radeon cards accepted a few years ago.